# Users chat using Rails + Nodejs (Redis, Socket.io, Mysql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, node.js, sockets, redis

I want to implement chat between users (like live Personal Messages) into my RoR application. So, after reading a lot of manuals and recommendations, i've decided to use nodejs + socket.io to handle socket connections and send\receive messages. How i  imagine it:

After user successfully signed in, rails adding **session key** to the redis db with associated **user id**. When user is opend PM's page, starts new connection through socket. When user presses button "Send", all data including **receiver id** and **message** sent to the server (nodejs). After that, nodejs extracting **session key** from cookie and checking redis db for existance. If exists -> check if user is subscribed to the specific channel ("channel-id1-id2" for example, where id1 and id2 - sender and recepient id), if true -> save message to db and send this message to channel subscribers (redis?), else -> create channel, save message to db and send this message to channel subscribers.

So, from what i have written, we use rails only for user authentication (if to take only PM module of my site). Questions:

1. Is logic of my application ok?
2. Is it safe to use channels for
       private messages? I mean if i be able to create channels and
       subscribe\unsubscribe users from it **ONLY** by nodejs server?
3. Any suggestions\corrections and etc. are Welcomed!

Thank you and remember that before posting this i have read different tutorials\manuals on this topic.

Comment: You might want to look at Action Cable, which will be included in Rails 5 (releasing any day now hopefully). https://github.com/rails/actioncable

Comment: @SeanHuber Thank you for the link! Maybe i'll find something usefull, but Rails can't handle many connections without serious performance loss. Thats why i'm looking in the side of nodejs

Comment: Good call on performance concerns (a lot of devs are skeptical of its usefulness). But yeah, if you dig into the debates of Action Cable maybe you'll find strategy tips of using sockets alongside rails.

Comment: @Srv just have a look at [pusher](https://pusher.com/) or [slanger](https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger) you can implement chat message as well as other features also(push realtime notifications to client on ) on the top of it

Comment: @sghosh968 First - i want it to be free. Second - if i understood it right, i can't use slanger to push messages to the server, so i'll need to use ajax..

Comment: @Srv yes you need to make ajax calls to push messages to server and then trigger event to push it to subscribed clients

Comment: @sghosh968 And that is why i can't use rails. It just really bad in handling requests. You can find a lot of information about it in the internet